# MySQL: avg per id in single column

Tags: mysql

For a graph I am asked to structure the data with an MYSQL statement.
It needs the following output (3 colums):

AVG_points | Playerid | Date

In the database I have dont have the average points per roundID, just the points scored per round per player.

its easy to calculate the current average points with avg(points) but I need the average points on every round so it can be plotted out in a graph.

I tried to make an SQL statement to give me the averages for every round but its not comming out in an useable format for graph to plot. I read into Pivotting but thats not what works in this situation, I think my sql is to simple, plus for every new round that comes up i need to program more lines wich means manual edits every table update to get the graph to work...

this what I tried:

```
SELECT   t1.playerid as player
    ,date_format(t1.CreatedTime, '%Y%m%d%H%i') as date

/* calculate average points per round */                

                ,(select avg(points) from pokermax_scores t2 where tournamentid <= (select distinct(tournamentid) from pokermax_scores order by tournamentid desc limit 0,1) and t2.playerid = t1.playerid) as avg_current
                ,(select avg(points) from pokermax_scores t2 where tournamentid <= (select distinct(tournamentid) from pokermax_scores order by tournamentid desc limit 1,1) and t2.playerid = t1.playerid) as 1_avg_last
                ,(select avg(points) from pokermax_scores t2 where tournamentid <= (select distinct(tournamentid) from pokermax_scores order by tournamentid desc limit 2,1) and t2.playerid = t1.playerid) as 2_avg_last
                ,(select avg(points) from pokermax_scores t2 where tournamentid <= (select distinct(tournamentid) from pokermax_scores order by tournamentid desc limit 3,1) and t2.playerid = t1.playerid) as 3_avg_last
                ,(select avg(points) from pokermax_scores t2 where tournamentid <= (select distinct(tournamentid) from pokermax_scores order by tournamentid desc limit 4,1) and t2.playerid = t1.playerid) as 4_avg_last
                ,(select avg(points) from pokermax_scores t2 where tournamentid <= (select distinct(tournamentid) from pokermax_scores order by tournamentid desc limit 5,1) and t2.playerid = t1.playerid) as 5_avg_last

FROM pokermax_scores as t1, pokermax_players as t3
GROUP BY player
```

which gives the following output: < SEE SQLFIDDLE LINK >

but I need my data in this format so PHP can loop it correctly:

http://i57.tinypic.com/10wists.png

Is there any SQL guru here that knows how I can edit my statement to make it come out as above picture?

thanks for reading all this :)

Here the SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a956f/2

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample data and desired results.  It is unclear what you are trying to produce.

Comment: thats why I used the screenshots to show the output and desired output

Comment: I still don't get it. What do those 'dates' in your desired result represent?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what your data really looks like.  The following would seem to be a good place to start because it produces the output in the format you want:

```
SELECT date(ps.CreatedTime) as date,
       ps.playerid as player,
       avg(ps.score)
FROM pokermax_scores ps
GROUP BY date(ps.CreatedTime), ps.playerid;
```

EDIT:

The comment helps.  You have nothing called "round" in the data.

I'm guessing it is `tournamentid`.  The query is easily modified if it is something else.  I think you want two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT date, player, avg(score)
FROM (SELECT date(ps.CreatedTime) as date,
             ps.playerid as player, tournamentid,
             SUM(ps.points) as score
      FROM pokermax_scores ps
      GROUP BY date(ps.CreatedTime), ps.playerid, tournamentid
     ) dpt
GROUP BY date, player;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a956f/11) it is in a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, however that gives me the total average score but i need average score per round, in my try I did this with LIMIT 0,1 and LIMIT 1,1 etc to exclude newer rounds when totalising the points to calculate average. I just made an SQLFIDDLE example of what I have now. and see above screenshot of what I was hoping it would be.

Comment: thanks for the example, but this returns just points per round but not average points for that round (example round 5 should give sum(points)/5) and not just points given in round 5.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to get cascaded sums on tournament points:

```
set @score_accumulator=0;
set @accumulator=0;

SELECT sub.tournamentId, 
        sub.datePS,
        -- SUM(@score_accumulator := @score_accumulator + sub.points) score,
        -- @accumulator := @accumulator + 1 nrTour,
       SUM(@score_accumulator := @score_accumulator + sub.points)/(@accumulator := @accumulator + 1) score
     FROM 
          (SELECT DISTINCT tournamentId,
           date(CreatedTime) AS datePS,
           points points
           FROM pokermax_scores ps2
           ORDER BY CreatedTime) sub
     GROUP BY sub.tournamentId ORDER BY sub.datePS
```

Similarly, you could to this for players points evolution.

That being said, this kind of logic should reside at **application level** and not **DB level**.

Comment: this gives indeed the same result as given by Gordon, but I am looking for avg scores per round over all rounds. round1 avg_points = sum(points for round1)/1 ,  round 2 avg_points = sum(points round1+round2)/2 , avg_points round3 = sum(points round1+round2+round3)/3 etc.

Comment: What you are mentioning is NOT per round average, but rather a global average at an certain point in time.

Comment: yes you are right Razvan, sorry for the confusion. after each round I need to calculate the current average. so I can plot out how the player is progressing in the tournament.

Comment: I made plot with just the points allready , but now I want one with the average points so its more clearly if a player is going up or down in the leaderboard. here is screenshot of plot i made of just points per round: http://i61.tinypic.com/2pu0qb6.png

Comment: I updated my answer with a query that might help you get the result set you want.

Comment: ah variables thats quite clever! I go play with it and try to make it so it shows player scores per round, though im new to variables :) I let you know. also with the date it needs date_format(t1.CreatedTime, '%Y%m%d%H%i') because we play more rounds per day, so it needs the timestamp

Comment: Almost there! Changed SQLFIDDLE data to reflect real data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01308/1       it shows the right format now but the averages are off. first round played at 18:00 hours (201504111800) player Baxico wins 38 points , so average should also be 38 for first round but it shows 24.3333

Comment: I think you're going to need a separate query for players, with other variables, as you mentioned, then join it with the output of the rounds query I mentioned.

Comment: will if I make it single query with variables, and just select one player in the where clause, the variables work perfectly. this was expected because every new line he devides +1 and since there only one player its one line per round (tournamentid). see this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/01308/30